# Split a string based on hyphen

Tags: sql, oracle, split, oracle8i

I have a string like this

```
XX0099-X01
```

I would like to split the string into two based on the hyphen, i.e.
`XX0099` and `X01`

I have tried as

```
SELECT 'XX0099-X01',
           SUBSTR('XX0099-X01',
                  1,
                  INSTR('XX0099-X01',
                        '-',
                        1
                        ) -1
                  )
    FROM   dual
```

Not sure how to get the second part.

We have an old legacy system which still using 8i Oracle database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using combination of `substr` and `instr`:

```
select 
  substr(s, 1, instr(s, '-') - 1),
  substr(s, instr(s, '-') + 1)
from t;
```

Another way is using `regexp_substr` if supported:

```
select 
  regexp_substr('XX0099-X01','[^-]+', 1, 1),
  regexp_substr('XX0099-X01','[^-]+', 1, 2)
from dual;
```

Comment: We have an old legacy system which still using 8i Oracle database, the above is not working in 8i. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: The "older version" (using standard string functions) is also likely to be faster than regular expression solutions in most cases. In general, regular expressions should be used only if a solution with standard string functions does not exist (or if the only such solutions are too complicated and cumbersome, becoming difficult to manage/maintain).

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use a regex substring/replacement, here is an option which uses Oracle's base string functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '-') - 1) AS first_part,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '-') + 1)    AS second_part
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated.